# POP3 E-mail Downloading Old E-mails I had Deleted

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, email

My Galaxy S3 phone recently received an update.  My POP3 e-mail via Comcast now downloads e-mails from several weeks ago, apparently when it wants and however many it wants, at the same time it checks for new e-mails.  I end up 'marking as read' and deleting these in bulk time and again.  I've tried NOT marking as read as well.  This did not happen until after the update.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked your server settings for POP3? It might not be set to "delete from server".

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the mail application to delete the messages from the server explicitly.  This options is provided during the initial setup, but is also accessible from the Account Setup options.  Change "Delete message from server" from "Never" to "When I delete from Inbox".

This was not part of my original answer, but was added by the editor:
This is fine if you do all your email on your handheld, but if you need to leave messages on the server for any reason (you deal with some later on computers at home or work) your android will keep grabbing other old messages to take their place until your set maximum is filled.  This seems to be a bug or at least a weakness in the platform.

Comment: This is untrue. I have a Samsung Tab 10.1 and an S2. The tablet will not download old messages but leave them for download when I get home. The S2 will download all messages over and over again. I read my mail on the go and deal with it at home. The tab does it but the phone does not.